# css last letter selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

Is there a way to style just the last letter in CSS?

I know that for the first letter I can use:

```
p::first-letter { 
    color: red;
}
```

But how to style the last letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `last-letter` selector instead wrap it in `span` and style it

```css
p::first-letter, p span {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<p>test test tes<span>t</span></p>
```